# Angular 6 CLI Workspaces. How to create library that exports services

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Background:

- Angular CLI 6 introduced the concept of workspaces.
- A workspace can contain multiple projects.
- The workspace and projects' configuration are in an 'angular.json' file in the workspace root folder.
- Each project can be either an application or a library.
- The CLI can generate a project that is a library with a command like this:

```
         ng generate library forms-lib
```

- This command creates a project of type
  'library' with a component and service and exports the component.

Question:

I am trying, without success, to create a library and make the services in it available for use in applications which need them.

This code does not work:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsLibComponent } from './forms-lib.component'; 
import { FormsLibService } from './forms-lib.service';

@NgModule({
    imports: [],
    declarations: [FormsLibComponent],
    exports: [FormsLibComponent, FormsLibService],
})
export class FormsLibModule {
}
```

Returns error:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't export value FormsLibService from FormsLibModule
as it was neither declared nor imported!
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: The default library template provided by the cli contains a service with `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })`, which seems to mean that you don't need to provide this service at the library level _or_ the app module (if you want a [singleton service](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services) that is). It _just works_!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might do the trick for you:

```js
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsLibComponent } from './forms-lib.component'; 
import { FormsLibService } from './forms-lib.service';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [FormsLibComponent],
    exports: [FormsLibComponent],
})
export class FormsLibModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
          ngModule: FormsLibModule,
          providers: [FormsLibService]
        };
      }
}
```

Comment: this solution will not work. i tried it. But importing statement in public_api.ts works

Answer (score 17):

You can add services you want to export from your library by adding some code into `public_api.ts`.

First locate `projects/nameOfLibProject/src/public_api.ts` inside your angular app then add

```
export * from './lib/locationOf/your.service';
```

Comment: I'm trying this approach (adding my service in public_api.ts), but when it i try to use a function within my service, it gives error this.mySvc.myFunction is not a function

Comment: @elesh.j did you import the service? here what i used `import { AlertsService } from '@myLib/commons-ng-core';` also make sure your lib is in your package.json

Comment: @elesh.j were you able to resolve the error? I'm also getting the same error this.service.function is not a function while trying to access the function.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you have missed to add your service in providers array on module.

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [],
    providers: [FormsLibService],
    declarations: [FormsLibComponent, FormsLibService],
    exports: [FormsLibComponent, FormsLibService],
})
```

Comment: Getting error while exporting service in Module. Only components, Modules,pipes and directives are allowed to export using above solution. for exporting service we need to have import statement in public_api.ts

Comment: To my knowledge, you don't need to export the services, you just include in the providers array in your module (as you are already doing it) and now consume it in app or another module by importing your module where your service is defined.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was: 
In the import statement, I picked what (Webstorm) autocomplete gave me, which was roughly the equivalent of

```
import {FormsLibModule} from 'forms-lib/lib/forms-lib.module';
```

Instead, I had to use only the library name:

```
import {FormsLibModule} from 'forms-lib';
```

(Note: I have a workspace which contains the library as well as the app that tests it)

Comment: Strangely enough this works. I wonder why it doesn't work the expected way though (happens to me with Angular 14 as well)...

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to the party, but for future references:
I got mine resolved by:

1. `ng build FormsLibModule`
2. Add the library's module to the target module and component files as follows:

> `import { FormsLibModule } from 'forms-lib';`

Note: VS Code shows this import as an error, but doesn't matter because it compiles fine. Don't try to use auto-import for this import because it is not listed there.

Comment: we are talking about creating a service in angular library and exporting from it. not about librarymodule.

Comment: This worked fine for me too. The trick to make it work with VSCode is to create a `exports.module.ts` file and add `export { FormsLibService } from 'forms-lib';` and use that on your imports. It will show as an error on VSCode but only in this file.

Answer (score 0):

As far as creating library under angular 8 is considered, we need to export service in public_api.ts 
`export * from './lib/components/spinner/spinner.service';`

Comment: same as angular 6