# How to consume a service from Angular Library in a project

Tags: angular, angular-library

I have a Angular 6 project which import an angular library.

I import components from library successfully, and now I'd like to have the AuthGuard Service in library, to share in all projects, but I can't do it.

I exported the AuthGuard in lib's public_api and provided in module, but I don't know how to access in project.

When I try to import like:

```
import { AuthGuard} from 'my-lib/lib/security/auth.guard';
```

I have the error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'my-lib/lib/security/auth.guard' in
>   'c:\workspace\my-project\src\app\portal'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50534543/angular-6-cli-workspaces-how-to-create-library-that-exports-services

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error seems you are missing some part.

Check
1.In `app.module.ts`

```
import { AuthGuard } from 'my-lib';
```

2. add `AuthGuard` in providers `providers: [AuthGuard, ...]`

3.In Module `import { AuthGuard } from 'my-lib';`

Comment: Thank you so much! I coudn't wrap my head around it... But now it works!

Answer (score 0):

You should import it directly from the lib.

```js
import { AuthGuard } from 'my-lib'
```

If this is not possible than you have incorrectly configured your lib.