# why modules can have methods to be used?

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular, still struggling in understanding modules.

I saw code from a book as below:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";

const routes: Routes = [{ path: "form/edit", component: FormComponent }]

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

and the author says:

**The forRoot method produces a module that includes the routing service**

I'm confused, how can a module to be used to access a function like `forRoot`, isn't that a module just declare components/directives to be used? how does CustomModule.CustomMethod() can even be used?

for example, the template to define a module is:

```
import ...

@NgModule({
 imports: [BrowserModule...],
 declarations: [AppComponent...],
 providers: [...]
})
export class AbcModule { }      //where can I define static CustomMethod?
```

there is no definition of static methods that can be used in AbcModule as:

```
AbcModule.CustomMethod()
```

Comment: `forRoot` is a *static* method in the `RouterModule`. If you declare a static method in one of your own modules, you can call that the same way.

Comment: @R.Richards  thanks for your answer. so how can I declare a static method in a module?

Comment: Basically, like this: `static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders { return { ngModule: AbcModule }; }`  https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-is-the-forroot-method. This is useful when building libraries for use in other projects.

Comment: @R.Richards  you mean the static method needs to be fined inside AbcModule just like defining a static method in a normal class?

Comment: Yes. See this old answer I posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50534543/angular-6-cli-workspaces-how-to-create-library-that-exports-services/50535930#50535930. May help you to see what it would look like in a real situation.

Answer (score 0):

A Module is just a "normal" class, with an @NgModule annotation.
So there's no reason that it can't have methods, including static methods like forRoot().